# Typescript - ignoring package without typings

Tags: typescript, types

I am looking at using an open source package without ts bindings.

I followed the [link here](https://github.com/microsoft/typescript/issues/3019) but had no luck.

I have tried to use `@ts-ignore` but it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone advise how I can ignore these errors for the time being?

```
//@ts-ignore
import { dummyMethod } from 'oss-package';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For packages without type bindings you should follow these steps

1) Create index.d.ts

2) Add there:

```
declare module 'oss-package'
```

If you want to declare the types of your methods:

```
declare module 'oss-package' {
    export const dummyMethod: () => any // this is optional
}
```

That's it, everything should work now.

Comment: Where should I create index.d.ts? Do I need to import it somehow?

Comment: @Newbyte The typescript compiler will check directories included in tsconfig for .d.ts files. A safe solution is to put it in your source root or project root.